Skylights have become foggy
We had skylights installed 5 years ago. Over time the opacity of the glass changed from clear (almost) to very cloudy. Assuming it's dust, we tried cleaning a small section with soap and vinegar but it doesn't seem to clear it up. Our suspicion is that the UV film has deteriorated.
Wondering if it is the deteriorated UV layer or just really tough dust. Any suggestions appreciated.

Update:
Image of the film


That's very strange. Was there packaging film on the glass that wasn't removed?

They are not like skylights I am used to seeing pictures of.  Look more like solar power/solar hot water system(but what do I know).

Yeah. They look as if they extend up above the roof in the picture.

Agreed, from the pic they don't look like skylights

To the OP: can you scratch at a corner with a razor blade and see if there's a film to be lifted?

They were clear when we got them. So the packaging film was definitely removed.

Yes there does appear to be a film. When I use a blade I can get under the film. Updated the original post with an image

Can you call the manufacturer and ask?  Perhaps there is a maintenance schedule on which the film should be replaced.  Perhaps it's under warranty.

From your last photo, it does seem like the film has deteriorated.  You should get back to the supplier.

Will reach out to the manufacturer and see if this is covered under warranty.
